# How to check value when using map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm converting some objects to JSON:

```
const tpL = results.map(post => ({
    ...post.toJSON(),
    postid: post.get("comment").id,
    commentid: post.get("post").id
  }));
```

But `post.get("comment")` or `post.get("post")` is not defined in every obejct. So I have to check if `post.get("comment")` is exist first.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want the resulting value at the properties to be if the `.get` doesn't return anything? Undefined?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want to skip that part. I dont want to set anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tpL = results.map(post => ({
    ...post.toJSON(),
    postid: post.get("comment") ? post.get("comment").id : null,
    commentid: post.get("post") ? post.get("post").id : null
  }));
```

PS note the return value adjusts to your defaults
This is similar to the solution above but allows you to set defaults

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a great use case for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
const tpL = results.map(post => ({
    ...post.toJSON(),
    postid: post.get("comment")?.id,
    commentid: post.get("post")?.id
}));
```

If the `.get` returns null or undefined, the resulting property value will `undefined`.

This is relatively new syntax, so it's not supported everywhere yet. (if you're putting this on a public website, hopefully your script is already being transpiled with Babel for cross-browser compatibility)

Comment: I will use thin in nodejs 12. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Depends on the production environment, if it's going to use Node 12 too then it's fine.

Comment: I get this error. postid: post.get("comment")?.id,
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: @UzaySan If it's always going to be run in an environment that supports optional chaining, then there's no issue, go for it. But optional chaining is first supported in Node 14. If it were me, I'd upgrade the Node version.

Answer (score 2):

Since Optional Chaining is not supported in every environments [nor every Browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=optional%20chaining), I'd suggest you to do as follow:

```
const tpL = results.map(post => ({
    ...post.toJSON(),
    ...(post.get("comment") && { postid: post.get("comment").id }),
    ...(post.get("post") && { commentid: post.get("post").id })
  }));
```

This way the objects of the array will contain the `postid` only if `.get("comment")` is defined and the `commentid` only if `.get('post')` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work and are elegant but you might miss that you can also use a full block of code as the body of the function you pass to `map()` and not just an expression (which `({ /*code omitted*/ })`) is. So you could also write

```
const tpL = results.map(post => {
   const res = post.toJSON();
   if (post.get("comment")){
      res.postid = post.get("comment").id;
   }
   if (post.get("post")){
      res.commentid = post.get("post").id;
   }
   return res;
});
```